# Android Jenkins logs showing "settings_apk-debug.apk: No such file or directory"

Tags: jenkins, appium

I am able to run the automation from windows terminal with android Gradle task, but when I tried same using jenkins terminal it shows below error:

```
appWaitActivity=com.example.TaskSelectionActivity, automationName=uiautomator2, unicodeKeyboard=false, deviceName=Android}]
    2019-09-24 16:17:10:208 - [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 
    'Command 'C\:\\Users\\jitu\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 1b544eb9 install 
    C\:\\windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\bin\\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; 
    Stderr: 'adb: failed to stat C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\bin\settings_apk-debug.apk: No such file or directory'; Code:
```

When I go to path I can see **settings_apk-debug.a**pk exist, but when we try to install via adb it shows " No such file or directory'; Code:"

Can somebuddy please help me on it?

Comment: have you set local variable for the ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: yes, adb command only works when you add ANDROID_HOME.